# Read xml file from url/HTTP in java

Tags: java, xml

Hello I have a big problem. I have to parse a XML file from URL/HTTP but it does not work.

Code :

```
try {           

    String url = "http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/a/gbp/2012-01-01/2012-01-31/";
    DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    f.setNamespaceAware(false);
    f.setValidating(false);
    DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
    URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(url).openConnection();
    urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
    Document doc = b.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    System.out.println ("Root element: " +  doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Error:

```
Connection timed out: connect
```

Comment: The URL visible in the code is reachable, therefore your Java program is not been able to access that external resource. Where are you running the program? Do you have any security manager enabled?

Comment: @SergioMontoro i running my program in eclipse

Comment: As Sergio said, Check your machine and the network your are connected to. The Url may be getting blocked by some security software. Also, can you access the url from your browser?

Comment: @amishra yes i can acces form my browser

Comment: can you ping to that url? if not then you may be behind some proxy and your browser may be configured with that proxy.